# CSS Grids auto (rest) size doesn't work for me

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm looking into CSS Grids and I've come across something weird. I want 3 columns: 1 and 3 are `150px` wide, and 2 is the rest. That should be possible, I thought, but this didn't work:

```
grid-template-columns: 150px auto 150px;
```

So I tried this, and that does work, but is silly:

```
grid-template-columns: 150px calc(100% - 300px) 150px;
```

And then I came across this example: http://gridbyexample.com/examples/code/layout1.html which uses this to make the content column auto size:

```
grid-template-columns: 200px 40px auto 40px 200px;
```

That's what I did! And their example works, and mine doesn't!?

My example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/w5xho67w/3/ (3 columns trigger if the screen >= 700px).

I must be doing something stupid, but I can't find the difference...

**Not it:**

- Because the `body` is `grid`
- Because it's an iframe
- Because the wrapper (`body`) isn't fixed width (neither `100%` nor `900px` works)

Comment: You dont have any external resources calling grid-template ?

Comment: @Levi External resources? Que?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the fractional units – set the middle column to be `1fr`, meaning that it will take up 1/1 of the remaining space when the two other columns are accounted for. It works (basically) like a flexbox flex unit with a `flex basis: 0`.

```
grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr 150px;
```

By contrast, the `auto` value will size according to content, so an empty middle column (for example) will not take up any space.

I've started writing a series on how the Grid Layout Module works, there is a [part on sizing grid tracks](http://thatemil.com/blog/2015/08/24/grid-tidbits-3-track-sizing) (which may be helpful) in there. :-)

Comment: You can combine `fr` with `px`? Weird... Any idea why the other website works with `auto`? It seems to do what I want to do, how I wanted to do it. Replacing their `auto` with `1fr` doesn't change a thing. Why doesn't my `auto` work? `auto` makes more sense...

Comment: Yes, 1fr for the middle col means "all the space left after distributing the total size of the 2 non-flexible tracks", i.e. anything other than tracks sized with fr. So you can mix and match fr, px, em, percentages, auto... I'm on mobile now, can't check other example, but presumably it has content that pushes the width out. Rachel has other examples of using flexible units on that site too, check them out. :)

Comment: Re: the auto thing: think of how it works with the height of blocks, rather than width, i.e. only as tall as content. In the context of a grid track, the track width works more like that.

Comment: I understand `fr`, but I don't understand why I need `fr` and gridbyexample.com can do the same with `auto`... In columns, like I'm doing.

Comment: Try removing the content inside the content column in the `auto`-example you linked to using the dev tools. You'll see that it collapses down to the minimum content size, for example if you remove the `p`-tags. Auto is defined as "at least as wide as the smallest minimum content size and at the most as wide as the maximum content size". The `fr` unit is not content-dependent.

Comment: Oooooooooooooooooooooooh! Ok, I get it now. Sorry =) Thanks man!